Measuring the accuracy after transforming function in logistic kernel
I have a non-parametric estimator using gaussian kernel and logistic kernel. Lets say estimation using Gaussian kerel is defined as $E_G$ and logistic kernel is defined as $R_L$. For increasing sample sizes I found that MSE (mean squared error) of $E_G$ is decreasing. When it comes to $E_G$ I received output as
overflow encountered in scalar power
  return np.exp(-z)/(1+np.exp(-z)**2)**2,
  RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in scalar divide
  return np.exp(-z)/(1+np.exp(-z)**2)**2,
  IntegrationWarning: The occurrence of roundoff error is detected,  
  which prevents 
  the requested tolerance from being achieved.  The error may be 
  underestimated.

If we use sigmoid function, then it is possible to control overflow, but it also includes error, and in this situation, is it fair to compare $E_G$ and $E_L$.
